# horizontal and vertical lines in a square

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Below is the image I am trying for, I managed to get a square using CSS, but I am trying for horizontal and vertical line in a square.

[image: Hub]

```
.hub{
   width: 119px;
   height: 101px;
   background: #b5adad;
}

<div class="hub"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this and one would be to use gradients like below: (*the image in question was actually a rectangle.*)

The approach is very simple - we use 2 linear gradients to create two thin solid colored lines and then position the images such that they match our needs. Linear gradients are used even though it creates only a solid color because it is easier to control size and position of an image than background color.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, red), linear-gradient(to right, red, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1px 100%, 100% 1px;
  background-position: 20px 0px, 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

We can also create an output which has a *fade-out* or *shadow* effect like in the image in question:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black), linear-gradient(to right, red, transparent), linear-gradient(to right, black, black), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, transparent);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
  background-position: 20px 0px, 21px 0px, 0px 10px, 0px 11px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome @pradeep. Please consider marking the answer as accepted (click the hollow tick mark below voting buttons on the side of the answer). That is usually how problems are marked as "solved" in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:

```css
.hub{
   width: 119px;
   height: 101px;
   background: #b5adad;
  position: relative;
  padding: 18px 0 0 18px;
}
.hub:after, .hub:before {
  content: " ";
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.hub:after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
}
.hub:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hub">Lorem ipsum dolor amet</div>
```

Comment: Yup, that's a valid approach too!

Comment: @Harry Nevertheless I like most yours